# parse.com presents a wrong SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, go, https, ssl-certificate

I'm using Parse.com to issue push notifications to my app users. I use golang's default http client to make the POST request. Whenever I load parse with many requests in the same time, it works normally for the first few requests and then I start getting this error for the following requests:

> Post https://api.parse.com/1/push: x509: certificate is valid for incapsula.com, trello.com, www.trello.com, not api.parse.com

And sometimes:

> Post https://api.parse.com/1/push: x509: certificate is valid for *.google.com, *.android.com, *.appengine.google.com, *.cloud.google.com, *.google-analytics.com, *.google.ca, *.google.cl, *.google.co.in, *.google.co.jp, *.google.co.uk, *.google.com.ar, *.google.com.au, *.google.com.br, *.google.com.co, *.google.com.mx, *.google.com.tr, *.google.com.vn, *.google.de, *.google.es, *.google.fr, *.google.hu, *.google.it, *.google.nl, *.google.pl, *.google.pt, *.googleadapis.com, *.googleapis.cn, *.googlecommerce.com, *.googlevideo.com, *.gstatic.cn, *.gstatic.com, *.gvt1.com, *.gvt2.com, *.metric.gstatic.com, *.urchin.com, *.url.google.com, *.youtube-nocookie.com, *.youtube.com, *.youtubeeducation.com, *.ytimg.com, android.clients.google.com, android.com, g.co, goo.gl, google-analytics.com, google.com, googlecommerce.com, urchin.com, youtu.be, youtube.com, youtubeeducation.com, not api.parse.com

Is it something wrong from Parse or am I missing something ?

EDIT:
As someone suggested in the comments. It was a DNS problem and it's now fixed. Thank you!

Comment: sounds like something is wrong with your dns

Comment: It was actually a DNS problem. Never thought of this. Thank you!